# Htaccess Redirect with Parameters split at

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is this by Redirect or RewriteRule possible with a htaccess?

This is old url:

```
mysite.com/showthread.php?28151-my-car&p=10
```

And this shoud be new one:

```
mysite.com/index.php?threads/28151/page-10
```

Thanks!

I have tried but couldn't split first parameter "28151-my-car" to only ID number(28151). I dont know which one is better, rewriterule or redirect.

```
RewriteRule showthread.php?$1&$2$ index.php?threads/(.*) [L]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to do ... Is `/index.php?threads/28151/page-10` an internal resource that actually exists and you only want to redirect a stale reference somewhere to the "new" URL, or`/showthread.php?28151-my-car&p=10`  the resource that should actually get called internally when the "new" URL `/index.php?threads/28151/page-10` gets called?

Comment: Hi arkascha, answer of RavinderSingh13 meets my requirements. Tnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. This treats you need to internal rewrite the URL and make sure `.htaccess` rules file and `index.php` file should be in same place. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/showthread\.php\?(\d+)-my-car&p=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?threads/%1/page-%2 [L]
```

***Generic Rules:*** Where its not matching literal `my-car` in spite of that it matches anything before `&`

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/showthread\.php\?(\d+)-[^&]*&p=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?threads/%1/page-%2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, your code works fine! Thank you!  Just one thing "-my-car" is an example, it could be any description. Is it possible to stop searching just before first'-' of the url ? mysite.com/showthread.php?28151(STOP SEARCH)-my-car(GO FUTHER)&p=10 
So the result be like this: mysite.com/index.php?threads/28151/page-10